# Userform resizing according to screen resolution

Tags: excel, vba, resize, zooming, userform

I have an Excel userform I want to resize on opening to fit the screen resolution.

I get the height and the width through `Application.Height` and `Application.Width`, and normally with these two parameters and the following code, one should do the trick:

```
Me.Top = Application.Top
Me.Left = Application.Left
Me.Height = Application.Height
Me.Width = Application.Width
```

Here is the problem: Windows (at least since 7) has a parameter to set the zoom on the desktop, and this seems to compromise the code.

[image: Screen resolution]

When changing from 100% to 150% for example, the form's width and height are set correctly but the zoom isn't. I'd like to change it according to Windows desktop zoom.

How can I retrieve the Desktop zoom parameter?

Comment: Have you tried using FullScreen mode on the UserForm? Does it attend to your application?

Comment: Well the code I put enables to put the Userform on FullScreen

Comment: Since `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "USER32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long` just gets the resolution. I read that you can get the zoom parameter from the registry entry. You should ask on Tags related to windows libs programming, they might know better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can someone point me towards what the zoom property on excel UserForm impacts. When changing it, it seems that it modifies the font size, the position of controls, but the font size of listView doesn't seem to change

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
'Function to get screen resolution
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As LongPtr) As Long
    'Functions to get DPI
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr 
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hDC As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    'Functions to get DPI
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
#End If
Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88  'Pixels/inch in X
Private Const POINTS_PER_INCH As Long = 72 'A point is defined as 1/72 inches

'Return DPI
Public Function PointsPerPixel() As Double
'hDC LongPtr if VBA7
 Dim hDC As Long
 Dim lDotsPerInch As Long

 hDC = GetDC(0)
 lDotsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
 PointsPerPixel = POINTS_PER_INCH / lDotsPerInch
 ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim w As Long, h As Long
    w = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' Screen Resolution width in points
    h = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' Screen Resolution height in points
With Me
    .StartUpPosition = 2
    .Width = w * PointsPerPixel * 0.5 'Userform width= Width in Resolution * DPI * 50%
    .Height = h * PointsPerPixel * 0.5 'Userform height= Height in Resolution * DPI * 50%
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr `

Comment: `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long `

Comment: (Separate comments to ensure that these separate lines of code aren't concatenated into a single block of text)   Also, you'll need a conditional declaration block in PointsPerPixel(), declaring hdc as Long and as LongPtr   -  Don't worry, the vast majority of published VBA pointer-safe declarations are wrong, and yours isn't actively dangerous: but I would prefer to see good examples for other developers.

Comment: @NigelHeffernan I updated the declarations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Application
    .WindowState = xlMaximized
    Zoom = Int(.Width / Me.Width * 100)
    Width = .Width
    Height = .Height
   End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Application

        Dim WD As Long
        Dim HD As Long
        Dim OrigW As Long
        Dim OrigH As Long

        Me.Width = 980.25 'Size the UserFrom was designed to
        Me.Height = 336.75 'Size the UserFrom was designed to
        WD = (Me.Width - Me.InsideWidth)
        HD = (Me.Height - Me.InsideHeight)
        OrigW = Me.Width
        OrigH = Me.Height

        Me.Width = (Application.Width / 1.481632653) 'The number you 
        'divide by should give you the original width of the UserForm 
        
        Me.Height = (((OrigH - HD) / (OrigW - WD)) * (Me.Width - WD))+HD

        Zoom = (((Me.Width) / OrigW) * 100)

        Me.Top = (Application.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)
        Me.Left = (Application.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is nearly 4.5 years old and already has two existing answers. How does this code differ from what's already here, and why is it better? Code is always more helpful when accompanied by an explanation. Please read [answer].